# What is the Perforce equivalent of "git reset --hard origin/master"

Tags: git, perforce

I am working on an legacy application which contain around a million(i mean, a lot files) files. Since i was very new to this, i made quite a lot of changes, without tracking which files i changed. Now builds are broken in my machine and i believe, its my change.

I want to do something like a "git reset --hard origin/master", which would clear my code and set it to latest code in repository.

I have tried getting the latest version. But, the build issue exist. I want to make sure that my code is clean. How do i do that in perforce?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to run `p4 clean`.

Comment: Also potentially `p4 revert //...` if you did actually open any files.

Comment: What if perforce doesn't detect any changes, but there are?

Comment: If perforce doesn't detect changes, I think you would want to use `p4 reconcile`